# Unconvertible character in message broker while fetching data from DB2

Tags: ibm-mq

We have developed a flow which does a transformation after it gets the data from DB2 stored procedure.  While doing the transformation in MAPPING node of wmb v7.0.0.5 we are facing this un  convertible recoverable exception. How to avoid this exception to occur.

Answer (score 0):

By default the the CCSID of your broker will be 819. But, I suspect the message you are posting have some characters which are not supported by CCSID 819.

To resolve this issue, you can set the MQMD.CCSID to 1208 as below:

```
SET OutputRoot.MQMD.CodedCharSetId = 1208;
```

However, I faced another issue with publication node. The publication node tries to convert the message into the queue manager's CCSID, before publishing. So, if your queue manager's CCSID is 819(lower CCSID than 1208) and publication node tries to convert the message(which contains special characters not supported by CCSID 819), then an exception will be thrown(unconvertible character).
Above case may also hold for mapping node. To resolve this try setting below:

```
SET OutputRoot.MQRFH2.(MQRFH2.Field)NameValueCCSID = 1208;  
SET OutputRoot.Properties.CodedCharSetId = 1208;
```

If you can put up a trace, then the exact cause will be clear.